# Linq query only works if written in dot notation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I wrote a query in dot notation and it works perfect:

```
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        return db.Person.OrderBy(m => m.LastName).ThenBy(m => m.FirstName).ToList();
    }
```

I then had to expand it with some joins, and because I am not that good with dot notation, I did it in query syntax.  I was getting a an error "Cant find an implementation of the query pattern" on the Person object.  I cut out all the joins and got it down to a query syntax version of the above query that works:

```
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        var query = from p in Person
                    select p;

        return (query).ToList();
    }
```

However, the above query is still getting the same error.  As far as I can tell, they are the same query.  My research shows the usual cause is something not implementing IEnumerable, but these queries are in the same class, 'Repository.cs' so they share the same using statements.  So how can one work and the other not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose it should be `db.Person` which implements the `IQueryable`.

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
{
        var query = from p in db.Person
                    select p;

        return (query).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Oh snap, I need more coffee.  Thank you.

Comment: Just a little overlook making big headaches. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, your query isn't the same as the "dotted" version.  Your original is ordered.  So aside from the main problem that you're not accessing the `Person` table correctly, your query should be more like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    var query = from p in db.Person
                orderby p.LastName, p.FirstName
                select p;

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: The point he was making was that he removed the ordering and it was still throwing an exception; even the `Select` didn't execute properly, so he wasn't even getting results, rather than having them in the wrong order.

Comment: Right, to correct the compiler error, he would have to access the `Person` table correctly. However I also addressed the fact that the two queries would not be equivalent which he may have overlooked.

Comment: It would appear that he had code just like this, and when it didn't work he removed the `orderby` line to see if *that* would work, with the intention of adding it back once he solved the underlying problem.

Comment: Perhaps, but then he stated "As far as I can tell, they are the same query" and with the code shown, well... it didn't seem that way. Oh well.